# attemps to access secure API in Blackberry

Tags: api, blackberry, installation

I have created one application and only design created and install in my **Storm** device  but when i want to show this desgn in only portrate then I wrote this line

```
Ui.getUiEngineInstance().setAcceptableDirections(Display.DIRECTION_PORTRAIT);
```

and install in device. I got error:

> attemps to access secure API

I have no idea what can I do? I had already signed this application before installing in the device.

Answer (score 2):

When you build the project check the log output - if your code uses any secure API the log will have an evidence of this by saying smth like:

> Warning!: Reference to class:
>   net.rim.device.api.system.Display
>   requires signing with key: RIM Runtime
>   API

If you get similar warning this means you need to sign you code file with signing keys got from RIM to be able to run the app on a real device (vs. simulator).

Comment: Thanx .when i delete .cod file clean emulator and run application in than i gor error msg "attemp to access secure API" i log .what can i do? plz help me i have already sign this application .

Comment: @droid.bb.dev: Hmm.. If your app is signed and you still get the error - I have no other ideas of what it coould be. :(

Comment: there is different key for real device and emulator ?

Comment: @droid.bb.dev: No, there is the only keys for signing (actually one keys set per developer account). BTW, you don't need to sign an app to run on a simulator. Signing is only needed for running on a real device.

Comment: thanx . i have already sign application but i cant open this apps in real device . if u have any other idea please help me .

Comment: @droid.bb.dev: The only idea I have: check that you sign your app properly - sometimes RIM server fails to respond quickly so you have to wait a bit till the all cods receive its signature response. Also check this tutorial on how to sign: http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=522

Answer (score 1):

does it work properly in the simulator?

Otherwise, try to delete the cod files and then run it on the simulator and then sign it properly

Also check the status during the signing process there may be some errors while signing

if it doesnot solve the problem,try cleaning the project and repeating the above process

Let me know if the problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

RIM requires several signatures to access protected classes (you can find a complete list on [Java APIs with controlled access](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/5779/Controlled_APIs_511406_11.jsp)).

You can request signature files using the form on the BB site (it request your name, surname, company and device's PIN). Once you got the signatures, you have to install them on Eclipse in order to load the application on a device. Therefore, accessing API like Crypto (developed by Certicom) needs another file, .RCC, but you have to request this file mailing the developer support of BB.